# Embedded Jetty: ServletContextListener that registers a ServletRequestListener

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty

I am using embedded Jetty v9.4.x and have the following issue:

My server registers a `ServletContextListener`:

```
    final WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();

    // add listener
    context.addLifeCycleListener(new AbstractLifeCycle.AbstractLifeCycleListener() {
        @Override
        public void lifeCycleStarting(LifeCycle event) {

            ContextHandler.Context ctx = context.getServletContext();
            ctx.setExtendedListenerTypes(true);
            ctx.addListener("LISTENER_CLASS_NAME");
        }
    });
```

My listener gets called on Servet start. However, my context listener registers a `ServletRequestListener` inside:

```
servletContext.addListener(foo.MyServletRequestListener.class);
```

And this fails with the following exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler$Context.addListener(ServletContextHandler.java:1506)
```

And when I looked it seems that context is not *enabled* (at least, this flags makes an exception to be thrown).

When I run the same application with the `web.xml` everything works.

How can I let the contextListener register a `ServletRequestListener`?

#### edit

There is explict note in Jetty code:

```
//toggle state of the dynamic API so that the listener cannot use it
```

This is enabled only on programatically added listeners - using API and not `web-xml`.

How I can make this work???

Comment: What interface does `foo.RequestContextListener` implement? (I ask, because `RequestContextListener` is not a valid Servlet Listener type)

Comment: It implements `javax.servlet.ServletRequestListener`

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt updated the question

Answer (score 7):

There are many different kinds of listeners in Jetty, each with their own specific set of add/remove/get/set methods.

Your `AbstractLifeCycleListener` is a Jetty LifeCycle listener, applying specifically for the Jetty internal starting/started/stopping/stopped of the various beans within Jetty.

Your implementation of this listener in your question is incomplete and shows a lack of understanding of the `LifeCycleEvent` (you are not looking for a specific bean to be started), your implementation will run hundreds of times. (once for each bean being started).

The use of [`ServletContext.addListener()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#addListener-java.lang.String-) has rules around it, and those specify that it can only be used during the `ServletContext` initialization phase (not before, not after).  The use of `ServletContext.addListener()` outside of this phase is supposed to throw an `IllegalStateException` (the javadoc even says so)

The `ServletContext.addListener()` also has a limited set of servlet Listeners that are allowed to be used with it, far less then the number of listeners types that are valid with a Web App, or can be declared within a `WEB-INF/web.xml`, or flagged with the `@WebListener` annotation.

The only way to use the `ServletContext.addListener()` is from within the webapp itself, using webapp code, from within the webapp's own classloader.

The places to use `ServletContext.addListener()` are ...

- [`ServletContainerInitializer.onStartup()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.html#onStartup-java.util.Set-javax.servlet.ServletContext-)
- [`ServletContextListener.contextInitialized()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextInitialized-javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent-)
- [`Filter.init()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html#init-javax.servlet.FilterConfig-)
- [`Servlet.init()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html#init-javax.servlet.ServletConfig-)

As you can see, all of these locations are defined from within the webapp itself.

The existence of `ServletContextHandler.addEventListener(EventListener)` is an embedded-jetty work around, which allows the Listener to be added on construction of the `ServletContextHandler`, but not called until the actual event occurs.

The use of `ServletContextHandler.addEventListener(EventListener)` is equivalent to using the `WEB-INF/web.xml` to declare the Listener you are interested in having be used.

Example:

```java
package jetty.listener;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequestEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequestListener;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;


public class ServletContextListenerExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Server server = new Server(8080);

        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler();
        context.setContextPath("/");

        MyContextListener contextListener = new MyContextListener();
        context.addEventListener(contextListener);

        // for context based static file serving and error handling
        context.addServlet(DefaultServlet.class, "/");

        HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
        handlers.addHandler(context);
        // for non-context error handling
        handlers.addHandler(new DefaultHandler());

        server.setHandler(handlers);
        server.start();
        server.join();
    }

    public static class MyContextListener implements ServletContextListener
    {
        @Override
        public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce)
        {
            System.err.printf("MyContextListener.contextInitialized(%s)%n", sce);
            sce.getServletContext().addListener(new MyRequestListener());
        }

        @Override
        public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce)
        {
            System.err.printf("MyContextListener.contextDestroyed(%s)%n", sce);
        }
    }

    public static class MyRequestListener implements ServletRequestListener
    {
        @Override
        public void requestDestroyed(ServletRequestEvent sre)
        {
            System.err.printf("MyRequestListener.requestDestroyed(%s)%n", sre);
        }

        @Override
        public void requestInitialized(ServletRequestEvent sre)
        {
            System.err.printf("MyRequestListener.requestInitialized(%s)%n", sre);
        }
    }
}
```

This will register `MyContextListener` which implements both `javax.servlet.ServletContextListener`.
When the `ServletContext` initialization phase kicks in, the  `contextInitialized()` event is triggered.
The implementation of `contextInitalized()` then uses the passed in `ServletContext` to add a new `MyRequestListener` (which implements `javax.servlet.ServletRequestListener`) via the `ServletContext.addListener()` API.

Output of the above, and hitting `http://localhost:8080/` from a browser ...

```
2018-06-28 09:42:06.352:INFO::main: Logging initialized @340ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
2018-06-28 09:42:06.475:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.11.v20180605; built: 2018-06-05T18:24:03.829Z; git: d5fc0523cfa96bfebfbda19606cad384d772f04c; jvm 9.0.4+11
MyContextListener.contextInitialized(javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent[source=ServletContext@o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@12e61fe6{/,null,STARTING}])
2018-06-28 09:42:06.532:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@12e61fe6{/,null,AVAILABLE}
2018-06-28 09:42:06.695:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@4567f35d{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2018-06-28 09:42:06.695:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @690ms
MyRequestListener.requestInitialized(javax.servlet.ServletRequestEvent[source=ServletContext@o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@12e61fe6{/,null,AVAILABLE}])
MyRequestListener.requestDestroyed(javax.servlet.ServletRequestEvent[source=ServletContext@o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@12e61fe6{/,null,AVAILABLE}])
```

> Caution: Be aware that there are many more listener APIs and listener types on Jetty then discussed here, they exist for other features / components with Jetty that are unrelated to your question.
>   Don't get hung up on them, skip them, ignore them and you'll be fine.

Comment: Actually no - I want to register the other listener when first starts. Here you register both listeners before server starts. I want to register 1 before and the other after server starts. This is what happens when web.xml is used, however Jetty detects that and make a difference if dynamic API is used (like in my case) or just web.xml. I wonder is there anyway to switch off this protection - and do not understand why it is there.

Comment: "first starts" and "after server starts" are meaningless events for your question, and do not apply to the phases of a ServletContext.  You have a much narrower set of events to work with.  It would be better to say "metadata declaration" and "context initialization phase" to fit within the events of the Servlet spec.

Comment: This is not related to ServletContext phases, but they way Jetty is working.

Comment: And Jetty's `ServletContextHandler$Context` is the implementation of `javax.servlet.ServletContext` with all of the same `ServletContext` rules that the Servlet spec has. (I've updated the answer)

Comment: Maybe I am not explaining this right... I do not have a problem to register `MyListener`. I have a problem to register another listener from `MyListener`. Try to register something in `MyListener#contextInitialized()`. This is valid in other containers and in jetty when parsing `web.xml`. After some debugging, I saw the explicit check for this use case.

Comment: Update code example shows your chain of actions with a simple `ServletContextHandler` (this is more complicated with a `WebAppContext` and its Classloaders).